# if with mulitiple empty checks and OR

Tags: php

i'm wondering why this condition dosn't work

```
if(!empty($b['boxText1']) || !empty($b['boxText2']) || !empty($b['boxText3']))) {
 // do something
}
```

i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in
```

am i missing something?

best

Comment: You are probably missing to take a look here first: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..........you typed extra ')'.....

```
if(!empty($b['boxText1']) || !empty($b['boxText2']) || !empty($b['boxText3'])) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($b['boxText1']) || !empty($b['boxText2']) || !empty($b['boxText3']) ) ) {
                                                                                ^
```

Remove the extra bracket you have used.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($b['boxText1']) || !empty($b['boxText2']) || !empty($b['boxText3'])) {
 // do something
}
```